# what is the difference between Oracle coherence and Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, in-memory, oracle-coherence

What is the difference between Oracle Coherence and Hadoop HDFS, have read about HDFS and coherence (but nothing was clear) sounds both doing the same. 
Whether these are different technologies addressing different problems or same Technology but different products?
Need to know the difference and similarity between them technology wise i.e. implementation perspective, in broader way, Where these two fit in?

Note: I am not asking for a product comparison(So no gorilla vs Shark).

Answer (score 6):

This two system are implementing two concepts.
HDFS - is distributed file system, optimized for massive sequential IO. 
Oracle Coherence is caching solution, capable of using disk for part of its data. It is optimized for random IO

Technologically : 
HDFS do not do any caching relaying on underlying OS for doing so. Its services (Datanode) should be considered as block device. 
Usual Cache solutions provide KeyValue abstraction, some expiration functionality and primarily use memory as a storage.  
Distributed cache is usually built using consistent hashing, while HDFS maintain centralized directory (NameNode). 
In the same time File System and Cache has a lot in common (if we look on file path as a key).

From the above : these to systems somewhat interchangeable but built for different scenarios and built completely different internally.

Comment: Thank David for the answer :)